# Remove column if it contains certain heading

Tags: r

When I read a file into my model, sometimes it contains a column named 'X' that just has the number of rows in the file. I can easily remove it but I would like to not have to check each time. How can I write an if statement that removes a column if its named X?
I already know what to put in the if statement

```
    df <- subset(df, select=-X)
```

| X | Values |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 150 |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This method will delete it if present and not throw an error if not present:

```
df[["X"]] = NULL
```

Or, as you say, you can write an `if` statement:

```
if("X" %in% colnames(df)) {
  df <- subset(df, select = -X)
}
```